# Trying to sum up values, so i can get a score for the "player" and the "UI"

Tags: javascript

I am making a blackjack game, and I'm trying to sum the values of the cards and make the score display when I press different buttons. I just need general help on different ways to sum up arrays with a random function and then display the array.

Comment: Can you provide some more information and code that you have tried?

Comment: In more classical models, card games are a perfect use case for enumerations.  While JS doesn't have a type of enum, you can mock enums using just an object with key value pairs.  ie:  var cards = { 2: 2, 3: 3, //etc , jack: 10, queen: 10, king: 10, ace: 11} and then during the game evaluation phase, if total value over 21 check if aces were played and do extra arithmetic to subtract 10 from each ace played.

Comment: I've tried making var sum = 0; Global and recalling it in a function like this: function showSum(){
            sum = sum + verdi[verdiIndex] + verdi[verdiToIndex];
            if (btnStart === true){
                sumSpiller.innerHTML = "Du har " + sum;
            }

Comment: I'm not sure what im supposed to put inside the "if", and how to make the sum appear when the button is pressed

Comment: If you have an array which you're storing all cards that have been played, to add them up you can use array method reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: [10,11].reduce((total, card) => total + card, 0)